# list.append(value) not adding anything

Tags: python, list, append

I wrote a simple program to add a string query (') to the end of URLs to check for mySQL errors.

### Here's the important parts of my program

```
vulnURLS = []

def checkforMySQLError(URL):
    global vulnURLS
    req = requests.get(URL, timeout=2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    soup_string = (str(soup))
    if "SQL syntax" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "mysql_fetch" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "mysql_num_rows" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "MySQL Error" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "MySQL_connect()" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "UNION SELECT" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    else:
        print ("\t [-] " + URL)
        print(vulnURLS)
```

All the print lines are working perfectly. But I'm appending the URL to no avail. Nothings getting added, no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

### Here's the full source code

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import socket
import threading
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import time
import ssl
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys
from functools import partial

vulnURLS = []
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def checkforMySQLError(URL):
    global vulnURLS
    req = requests.get(URL, timeout=2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
    soup_string = (str(soup))
    if "SQL syntax" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "mysql_fetch" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "mysql_num_rows" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "MySQL Error" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "MySQL_connect()" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    elif "UNION SELECT" in soup_string:
        vulnURLS.append(URL)
        print ("\t [+] " + URL)
    else:
        print ("\t [-] " + URL)
        print(vulnURLS)

def tryMethod(req):
    try:
        checkforMySQLError(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 404:
            print("\t [-] Page not found.")
        if e.code == 400:
            print ("\t [+] " + req)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("\t [-] URL Timed Out")
    except socket.timeout as e:
        print("\t [-] URL Timed Out")
        pass
    except socket.error as e:
        print("\t [-] Error in URL")
        pass

def mainMethod(URLList):
    URL = URLList.replace("\n", "")
    URL = URL.replace("https://","http://")
    URL = URL.replace("\s", "%20")
    URL = (URL + "'")
    tryMethod(URL)

def mp_handler(URLList):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    p.imap(mainMethod, URLList)
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__=='__main__':
    URLList = open('sites.txt', 'r')
    mp_handler(URLList)
```

As I said, all the print-lines are working perfectly, so I know the code is running correctly. But why is nothing being added to my list? I've been stuck on this for two hours, I feel ridiculous.

### Here's some of the result coding to prove I'm not always getting the else case (I print the list after every iteration)

```
C:\Users\Brice\Desktop\b>py SiteHunter.py
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://m.jccal.org/Default.asp?ID=840'
[]
         [-] http://www.splitcoaststampers.com/gallery/showgallery.php?cat=3089'
[]
         [+] http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'
         [-] http://wisc.jobs/public/links_summary_page.asp?catid=85'
[]
         [-] http://www.ceciliareynoso.com.ar/page.php?lang=es&album=7&id=28'
[]
         [-] http://www.snejbjergcykelmotion.dk/pages/webside.asp?articleGuid=47645'
[]
         [-] http://www.pcmusic.org/about/team.php?lang=en'
[]
         [-] http://www.thehealthsite.com/wp-content/themes/health2014/images/health-logo.png?v=20170617-V1'
[]
         [-] http://www.ipdia.com/index.php?page=our_products'
[]
         [-] http://cosmet.ac.jp/mt4i/mt4i.cgi?id=11&mode=individual&eid=1169'
[]
         [-] http://www.timeworx.co.nz/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=59'
[]
         [-] http://www.e-scow.org/content.aspx?page_id=22&club_id=180842&module_id=129141'
[]
         [-] http://www.andersonsbooks.com/searchResults.php?category_id=332&action=browse'
[]
         [-] http://www2.ub.edu/assessling/cgi/consultes/resposta.pl?consultes_id=743'
[]
         [-] http://www.butterpaper.com/vanilla/comments.php?DiscussionID=1095'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://www.zombierunner.com/cgi-sys/cgiwrap/zr/sc/order.cgi?storeid=*1241f8a65e9100618c5065&cert=gift'
[]
         [-] http://www.mcspaddendulcimers.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=18'
[]
         [-] http://www.tumbletots.com/programmes.php?ID=4'
[]
         [-] http://ventas.ticketplus.com.pa/ordertickets.asp?p=4324'
[]
         [-] http://www.thebestpageintheuniverse.net/c.cgi?u=buzzfeed'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://ufw.org/_page.php?menu=about&inc=about_exe.html'
[]
         [-] http://643boxbreaks.com/browse.php?id=198'
[]
         [-] http://wiki.carleton.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8717123'
[]
         [-] http://champersrestaurant.com/index.php?categoryid=16'
[]
         [+] http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'
         [-] http://www.german-profec.com/cms/front_content.php?idcat=100'
[]
         [-] http://www.manuela-maurer.ch/default.aspx?navid=6'
[]
         [-] http://wms.wusd13.org/index.cfm?pID=4809'
[]
         [-] http://www.doctortyre.it/index.php?option=com_phocagallery&view=category&id=1&Itemid=190'
[]
         [-] http://www.coldplay.com/newsdetail.php?id=1531'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://www.nantucketlittleleague.com/getpdf.php?id=19'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [-] http://www.usw745.org/index.cfm?action=cat&categoryID=2631168f-fc4d-4b5f-a640-9df545603e29'
[]
         [-] http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A601'
[]
         [-] http://www.integro-usa.com/Store/default.asp?categoryID=10'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://www.humhotels.hr/hotels_details.asp?id=6'
[]
         [-] http://krolldesign.co.il/works.asp?catid=2&subcatid=7'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [-] http://www.qrz.com/cgi-bin/ikonboard.cgi?s=3f3438492d5effff;act=ST;f=7;t=41245'
[]
         [-] http://forum.slowtwitch.com/gforum.cgi?post=1612485;search_string=runtraining'
[]
         [-] http://www.elgressy.com/list.asp?categoryId=287&id=763'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://fireflylisting.com/listing.php?id=1060'
[]
         [+] http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://vestas.taleo.net/careersection/jobdetail.ftl?job=170001ZZ'
[]
         [-] http://www.biblioteca.juriquilla.unam.mx/gsdl/cgi-bin/linux/library.cgi?e=d-01000-00---off-0cgeo--00-1----0-10-0---0---0direct-10----4-------0-1l--11-es-50---20-about---00-1-1-00-00--4--0--0-0-11-10-0utfZz-8-00&a=d&c=cgeo&cl=CL4.4'
[]
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://www.icms.org.uk/workshop.php?id=299'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [-] http://owentrailers.com/products/products.asp?cat=darkrides'
[]
         [-] http://www.deaftravel.co.uk/directorydetails.php?id=26'
[]
         [-] http://www.willdan.com/newsDetail.aspx?NewsID=Willdan-Announces-New-Board-Appointments'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [-] http://www.lawtv.kr/bbs/board.php?tbl=notice&mode=VIEW&num=2&chr=&category=&findType=&findWord=&sort1=&sort2=&program_code=&page=1'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://www.thebarbiecollection.com/shop/OrderStatusGuestView?storeId=10154&langId=-1&catalogId=10551'
[]
         [-] http://www.enom.com/help/hostinghelp.aspx?hosthelp=9'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [-] http://cai.caionline.org/eweb/DynamicPage.aspx?site=CAI&WebCode=storeItemDetail&parentKey=0b859898-096b-4890-8293-c7256d54423b'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [-] http://www.haganenet.co.il/content.asp?pageID=6215'
[]
         [-] http://wiki.contrexx.com/en/index.php?title=New_Module'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://www.kartell.com/cms/legal/useterms.asp?tskay=52EE612B'
[]
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://www.sungkwang21.org/board/view.php?id=gallery&npage=1&mode=view&idx=1483&search_text='
[]
         [-] http://dsgr.org/cpage.php?pt=138'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [+] http://isindexing.com/isi/journaldetails.php?id=327'
         [-] http://www.sofame.com/modules.php?op=modload&name=News&file=article&sid=195&newlang=eng'
[]
         [-] http://www.eas.sk/mod/product/show.php?ID=59'
[]
         [-] http://www.jzsjxw.gov.cn/nskslist.asp?ztid=304'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'"]
         [-] http://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/downloads.php?do=file&id=16716'
[]
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://csn.augusoft.net/index.cfm?fuseaction=1010'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [+] http://www.bajantube.com/play-video.php?videoid=8'
         [-] http://www.inaya.com.kw/contactus.aspx?Pid=1019'
["http://isindexing.com/isi/journaldetails.php?id=327'"]
         [-] http://www.przemysl.ap.gov.pl/index.php?c=page&id=61'
[]
         [-] http://www.tmbvacuum.com/file-prodotti.php?id=31'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [-] http://www.ashanet.org/projects/project-view.php?p=636'
[]
         [-] http://uplnd.com/products/detail.php?product_id=170190768'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [-] http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/?pid=15349'
["http://aaqct.org.ar/capacitacion/single.php?id=1'", "http://www.bajantube.com/play-video.php?videoid=8'"]
         [-] http://www.sanin-chuo.co.jp/shashin/modules/news/photonews.php?topicid=203'
[]
         [-] http://aencore.com/pro/list.php?pid=130&f=129'
[]
         [-] http://www.quanjinglian.com/portal.php?mod=topic&topicid=65'
[]
         [-] http://secy.klk.com/navigation/categorylist.asp?MySessionID=119-431116457&CatID=14'
[]
         [-] http://sanctuarysimon.org/projects/project_info.php?projectID=100391'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [-] http://thetourismcompany.com/topic.asp?topicid=31'
[]
         [-] http://rusmusic.su/song.php?id=36'
["http://si.chanwanich.com/technologydetail.php?id=8'"]
         [-] http://percichester.com/Asset.asp?AssetID=71806&AKey=MCFLQYDL'
["http://www.nlcng.org/newsview.php?viewarticleactiveschool=85'"]
         [+] http://www.mazetrivia.com/viewmaze.php?id=77'
         [-] Error in URL
         [-] http://www.sheffieldphoenix.com/showbook.asp?bkid=637'
[]
         [-] http://www.lexingtonnc.net/modules/showdocument.aspx?documentid=1581'
[]
         [-] http://www.investor.nexteraenergy.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=88486&p=earningsRelease'
[]
```

### EDIT: I see that it is adding to the list, but immediately clearing after. Why is this?

Comment: You always print your  URL, even in the `else` case, where you don't append them to the list; Are you sure that you're not always in this case?

Comment: May be you are always getting into the else case. Sure about that?

Comment: I get URLs returned with a [+]. I'm sure that it's not the problem.

Comment: I just added some result code to prove it.

Comment: Now I can see that it is adding some URLs to the list, which are getting immediately replaced.

Comment: Run it without multiprocessing and I bet it'll work just fine. At a minimum, you're suffering from `vulnURLS` being updated in each subprocess, not in the parent process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `multiprocessing.Pool`. This creates processes, not threads. Memory is not shared between processes, like it is between threads, so each of your workers has its own copy of the `vulnURLS` list. You need to redesign your program to either use threads or have the processes return lists, and then concatenate them in main process.

Comment: This is unfortunate as multi-processing has been significantly quicker than multi-threading, but you are absolutely right. Multi-threading seems like a much easier solution than having each process return a list and combining them.

Comment: Check this out too: [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) You can send some data between processes, but it is not that easy :)

Comment: @K.Kirsz Thats overkill when there's everything to exchange data built into multiprocessing. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers shows using a pool and getting results from it.